# Why am I getting server replied forbidden from google drive rest api?

Tags: qt, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

**My Goal:**

I am trying to connect my Qt desktop app with google drive. Right now my goal is simple i.e get list of all files from my drive (In JSON form)

**What I have done so far.**

I have followed this tutorial [Connecting your Qt application with Google Services using OAuth 2.0](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/25/connecting-qt-application-google-services-using-oauth-2-0/) and created my own wrapper class for it. I have followed all the steps till grant() function is called. The scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`. Everything is working fine till now.

I used the signal `tokensReceived` emitted from `QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler` and stored the access_token. So in short I am able to authenticate my application and get the access token. Now the next step for me is to perform a simple get request. This is what I have done

```
void Google_Drive::Send_Request()
{
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files"));
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization", QByteArray("Bearer ")+mAccessToken);
    mManager.get(request);
}
```

**Error I am getting:**

Reply I am getting is

> "Error transferring https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files - server replied: Forbidden"

Please let me know what I am missing or am I doing something wrong. Also if any additional detail is required let me know. Thank you!

**Edit 1:**
In reply recieving method this time I `readAll()` instead of just reading `errorString()` and I found that the api was not turned on. So I turned On the api from developer console. Now I after setting that Now I am getting the `errorString()` as

> "Error transferring https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about -
>   server replied: Bad Request"

and from `reply->readAll()` returns

> "{\n \"error\": {\n  \"errors\": [\n   {\n    \"domain\":
>   \"global\",\n    \"reason\": \"required\",\n    \"message\": \"The
>   'fields' parameter is required for this method.\",\n
>   \"locationType\": \"parameter\",\n    \"location\": \"fields\"\n   }\n
>   ],\n  \"code\": 400,\n  \"message\": \"The 'fields' parameter is
>   required for this method.\"\n }\n}\n"

**Edit 2:**
My apologies, to test the response I was using "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about" instead of "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files". Now correcting it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forbidden most likely means theirs something wrong with the access token or the way your applying it.

Easiest way to test it is to do this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?access_token=Yourtoken
```

You can either add it to your code or just put it in a web browser since its a http get call.

If the access token works then you know there is something wrong with the way you are applying the authorization header.

```
QString headerData = "Bearer " + mAccessToken;
request.setRawHeader("Authorization", headerData.toLocal8Bit());
```

**The 'fields' parameter is required for this method.**

This is an undocumented required field in the google drive api.  You must send fields=* with all your requests.

> fields Selector specifying a subset of fields to include in the response.
>   For more information, see the partial response section in the Performance Tips document.
>   Use for better performance.

try and add this

```
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=*"));
```

Comment: It has no problem, i confirmed with your test.

Comment: My guess setting it to a QByteArray is probably a bad idea. bearer is just text

Comment: I tried that one too, same response, please check my edit

Comment: Sorry It was my mistake, i was using wrong request check my edit 2

Comment: fields=* will help you get back the full response anyway your only going to get a partial response if you dont add it.   Remember to accept the anwser if it helped you.