# Unable to implement Google Sign-In using QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow

Tags: c++, qt, oauth-2.0, qt5, google-authentication

The issue is with redirect URIs, I don't know what to set it to. Hase ANYONE been able to figure this out?

I get an error in `Qt Creator's` output pane that looks like this:

```
qt.networkauth.oauth2: Unexpected call
qt.networkauth.replyhandler: Error transferring https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token - server replied: Bad Request
```

Here's my code, a function called `grant()` that will return true open successful authentication. The helper class `OAuth2Props` returns all the data from the JSON file generated by Google.

```
bool grant() {
  QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow oauthFlow;
  QObject::connect(&oauthFlow,
                   &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizeWithBrowser,
                   &QDesktopServices::openUrl);

  oauthFlow.setScope("email");
  oauthFlow.setAuthorizationUrl(OAuth2Props::authUri());
  oauthFlow.setClientIdentifier(OAuth2Props::clientId());
  oauthFlow.setAccessTokenUrl(OAuth2Props::tokenUri());
  oauthFlow.setClientIdentifierSharedKey(OAuth2Props::clientSecret());
  QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler oauthReplyHandler(
      QUrl(OAuth2Props::redirectUri()).port());
  oauthFlow.setReplyHandler(&oauthReplyHandler);

  QEventLoop eventLoop;
  QObject::connect(&oauthFlow, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::granted,
                   &eventLoop, &QEventLoop::quit);
  oauthFlow.grant();
  eventLoop.exec();

  return true;
}
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? The redirect URI I have set to `http://127.0.0.1:65535/`, I am guessing that's what I am doing wrong?

**Update:**

1. The following code is working, the reason I was having trouble was because after getting authorized once, I was running the code again and since I was already authorized I was getting this error.
2. It's probably better to create an instance of `QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow` on the heap, like @Chilarai is doing in his sample code. Because we don't want our `QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow` to go out of scope anyways, since we are going to be needing it to make further requests.
3. Another important note here is to connect to `QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler::tokensReceived` signal, in order to get the token needed to further interact with your Google service.
4. The token can later be tested if it is still valid through a Google REST Api, here's one way to do it, if you want to interact with `Google Drive` you can try what this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52181208/why-am-i-getting-server-replied-forbidden-from-google-drive-rest-api) suggests.

Comment: Hi @armanali, looks like you have some troubles with QtNetwork and not with google apis. Which OS are you testing with? Linux, Windows? Do you have OpenSSL and Crypto libs in correct place? To get more Debug from networkauth do this: #include <QLoggingCategory> and set QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules("qt.networkauth.*=true"); on first line of your main() function

Comment: @Xplatforms, I am testing it with Windows for now. I did install OpenSSL from Qt installer and I did add this to my path `C:\Qt\Tools\OpenSSL\Win_x64\bin`. I will try your suggestions. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: And in my .pro file I have added `QT += core gui networkauth`

Comment: I did what you were suggesting, but didn't get any meaningful debug messages

Comment: just tested my old code for it and it fails too on https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token . But if you connect to QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler::callbackReceived slot you can see authufer code,etc. try to set own QNAM Subclass with setNetworkAccessManager to debug the oAuth flow. Or switch to amazon oauth2 like I did :D

Comment: @Xplatforms, my goal is to implement Google Sign-In from my app, since later on I'm gonna have to use other Google services. How does Amazon OAuth2 help? Does Amazon have an OAuth2 library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a hard time debugging it. But, I have realized that if you goto Google console and set the Redirect URI to `http://127.0.0.1:some_port/` instead of `http://localhost:some_port/`

Remember to put '/' in the end

it magically works. Rest here is my code

```
    this->google = new QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow(this);
        this->google->setScope("email");

        connect(this->google, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizeWithBrowser, &QDesktopServices::openUrl);

        this->google->setAuthorizationUrl(QUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"));
        this->google->setClientIdentifier(CLIENT_ID);
        this->google->setAccessTokenUrl(QUrl("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"));
        this->google->setClientIdentifierSharedKey(CLIENT_SECRET);

// In my case, I have hardcoded 5476 to test
        auto replyHandler = new QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler(5476, this);
        this->google->setReplyHandler(replyHandler);
        this->google->grant();


        connect(this->google, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::granted, [=](){
            qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << __LINE__ << "Access Granted!";

            auto reply = this->google->get(QUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me"));
            connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [reply](){
                qDebug() << "REQUEST FINISHED. Error? " << (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError);
                qDebug() << reply->readAll();
            });
        });
```

For details on the rest of the code, refer this [How to create a login page using Qt oauth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453550/how-to-create-a-login-page-using-qt-oauth/62382316#62382316)

Comment: That's what I have, http://127.0.0.1:65535/, but it's still not working. I'll try it again using your solution as a reference. Also, can you please show/post how you configured your Google Auth 2.0 credentials? You can just post the JSON's keys without the values. Thank you!

Comment: Here are my JSON KEYS. Remember, I have hardcoded the values above in my code

`{"web": {"client_id": "CLIENT_ID","project_id": "TEST","auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret": "CLIENT_SECRET","redirect_uris": ["http://127.0.0.1:5476/"],"javascript_origins": ["http://localhost", "http://localhost:5476"]}}`

Comment: I have implemented a sample project with all the details on Github. You may want to check out the project here https://github.com/chilarai/Qt-Google-OAuth

Comment: By the way, I tried your code and it worked fine as well. It must be incorrect redirect uri or port somewhere which is creating the issue

Comment: I am getting the following error in Qt Creator `qrc:/main.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" version 2.15 is not installed`. I am using Qt 5.14.2 and I checked the Qt Installer tool and there is no option of adding Qt Quick separetely, I am guessing it's part of the core in version 5.14.2. What version do you have?

Comment: Btw, it builds fine, I get that error when trying to run your app.

Comment: I am using Qt SDK version 5.15.0 and the latest version of QtQuick 2.15. Now since you are using sdk v5.14, so you have to downgrade your QtQuick to 2.14.

Comment: There is no way to specially install QtQuick. It comes inbuilt with the sdk. 
However, the code should run fine with SDK v5.14 as well

Comment: I got it to work too. I think I always had it working. The reason that got the Bad Request error was because once getting authorized I would do it again and it's not needed. Because you only need it authorized once. Then later if you go to your Google App (like Google Drive) and remove your app, then you can do it again. This arises another question. How to check if you need authorization, so you don't have to ask for it again. It may be solved at an application level I am guessing.

Comment: When you are calling from QML, call a function with only **grant()**. Rest of the code should be in constructor. It will solve the problem. Check the code here
https://github.com/chilarai/Qt-Google-OAuth

Also you need to ask for permissions every time if you use **networkauth** else you don't get the required data

Answer (score 2):

In light of Google's move to block OAuth requests from embedded web views, we have published an explanation on [how to authenticate with Google SSO in Qt](https://appfluence.com/productivity/how-to-authenticate-qt-google-sso/), with several pointers to get started, and troubleshooting the common problems in the official solutions.

The more common problems we found are:

- The solution in the Qt examples makes you use the wrong redirection URL
- The login code returned by Google needs to be UR>-decoded inside the authentication flow
- The interaction between JS and C++ has changed

Comment: A great post from a fellow Anteater. Thank you!:)

Comment: Zot, zot! Thanks @aalimian :)